# Prove that $\lim_{x \to2 }x^{2}+4x=12$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my prove

we begin by

$$x^{2}+4x-12<\epsilon $$

$$|x+6||x-2|<\epsilon $$

I will prove by use property 
$\lim_{x->n}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x->n}f(x)\lim_{x->n}g(x)$

then we divide into to case

$|x+6|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$ and $ |x-2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$

and let$\epsilon ,\delta _{1}\delta _{2}>0$

$$0<|x-2|<\delta _{1}\rightarrow |x+6|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

Choose $\delta _{1}=\sqrt{\epsilon }$

then $|x+6|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$

$$0<|x-2|<\delta _{2}\rightarrow |x-2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

Choose $\delta _{1}=\sqrt{\epsilon }$

then $|x+6|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$

then use property $\lim_{x->n}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x->n}f(x)\lim_{x->n}g(x)$

we get

$$|x+6||x-2|<\sqrt{\epsilon }\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

then $\lim_{x->2}x^{2}+4x=12$

Comment: Pretty good show of effort! I haven't looked through the proof yet, but +1 just for following the question guide correctly, if only in order to encourage more of it!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thank you ^ ^

Comment: @Lingnoi401: There is a strange mix between $\lim_{x\to n}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}$. But the main problem is that you cannot ask $x$ to, in the same time, close to $-6$ and close to $2$.

Comment: oh i  mistype  -*-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct when you write $|(x^2+4x-12)| = |x+6||x-2|$, but after that, you are not doing the right thing.

The mistake is in the line : $0 < |x-2| < \delta \implies |x+6| < \epsilon$. You can check that no $\delta$ will satisfy this, the limit does not hold. There also seems to be a confusion between usage of theorem and proceeding by definition.

You know that $\lim f(x)g(x) = \lim f(x) \lim g(x)$.

At this point, one crucial thing : if you are using this identity, then there is no point of starting with "let $\epsilon > 0$". What you have to do now, is to show individually that $\lim f(x) \lim g(x) = 0$ (since $f(x)g(x)= x^2+4x-12 \to 0$ is expected as $x \to 2$).

Hence, if you can show that both limits exist, and their product is zero, then you are done.

Now, begin your $\epsilon-\delta$ argument. Let $\epsilon > 0$ (I'll prove both limits together).

Let $\delta = \epsilon$. Then, note that $|x-2| < \delta \implies |(x-2) - 0| < \epsilon$. Hence, $\lim_{x \to 2} (x-2) = 0$.

Let $\delta = \epsilon$. Note that $|x-2|  < \delta \implies |(x + 6) - 8| < \epsilon$. From here, it follows that $\lim_{x \to 2} x + 6 = 8$.

Now, from this you get the product of the limits as $0 \times 8 = 0$. Hence, $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2+4x- 12 = 0$, from which you see that $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2+4x = 12$.

The point here is, first it looked like you started by  definition, and then it looked like you wanted to use a theorem. So if you make your mind up clearly on what you want to do, it would have been easier (like this).

Comment: that mean if use the property I must prove each limit of |x-2| and |x+6| are correct before conclude it is true?

Comment: Right, that is correct. You must show each limit exists, find the values of the limit, and  then use the property.

Comment: You are welcome. A change of username, I see.

Comment: If you use product of limits, why not just write $\lim_{x\to 2}(x^2+4x) = (\lim_{x\to 2}x)^2+4(\lim_{x\to 2}x) = 2^2+4\cdot 2 = 12$?

Comment: @Ennar You are correct about that, but since the questioner completed a factorization, I thought I would go that way.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

We wish to find a $\delta>0$ such that if  $\vert x-2\vert<\delta$, then $\vert x^2+4x-12\vert<\epsilon$.

We see that the $x^2-4x-12=(x-2)(x+6)$. Since $x\to2$ we can assume that eventually it will be true that $\vert x-2\vert<1$ which means that

\begin{eqnarray}
-1&<&x-2<1\\
1&<&x<3\\
7&<&x+6<9
\end{eqnarray}

so we see that if $\vert x-2\vert<1$ then $\vert x+6\vert\le9$

So we let $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{9}\right\}$

Now if $\vert x-2\vert<\delta$ it follows that

\begin{eqnarray}
\vert x^2+4x-12\vert &=& \vert x+6\vert\cdot\vert x-2\vert\\
&<&9\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{9}\\
&<&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Note that for many limits (there are exceptions) you can find an upper bound $B$ so that

$$\left\lvert\dfrac{f(x)-L}{x-a}\right\lvert\le B$$

whenever $\vert x-a\vert<1$. In such a case you can let $\delta=\min\left\{1,\dfrac{\epsilon}{B}\right\}$.

This will not work in cases where there is a vertical tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$.

Comment: I 've seen this method in the book,but didnot get it ,that why I use the property for proof instead ,but thank you for help  ^ ^